# Discord Embed image not working in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

I'm making a bot with discord.py and I want to send the mentioned user's avatar with a glass filter.. This is my code

```
import aiohttp
import json
import requests

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=']')

#glass filter
@bot.command()
async def glass (ctx,*,person:discord.Member =None) :
  member = ctx.message.author
  person: discord.Member
  embed = discord.Embed ()
  mentiondp = member.avatar_url
  embed.set_image (url = f'https://some-random-api.ml/canvas/glass?avatar={mentiondp}' )
  await ctx.send (embed=embed)
```

But when I tried **]glass @DankMemer** It sends a blank embed..

Please Help me!

[image: issue]

Answer (score 1):

Currently Discord embeds are down. You'll need to wait a bit until they fix it.
[https://discordstatus.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTs9v.png)

Comment: Ohh Thank you for informing!

Comment: But my other embeds are working!

Comment: Have you checked if the image URL is working? It returns an HTML page with an <img> element in it... You would need to get the URL from there as well. @RovinduThamuditha

Comment: Yeah But Now I realized that  the api is not working :(